# Propagate state of Kafka connection to readiness actuator indicator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a basic spring boot service that sends messages through Kafka.

When kafka connection is down, spring boot `actuator` shows the status of kafka binder as `DOWN` and overall status as `DOWN`. However, `Readiness` and `Liveness` are both `UP`.
I would like however the down status of kafka binder to be propagated to `Readiness` indicator.

That means, if kafka is up, I'd like `localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness` to show `"UP"` and when kafka is down, I'd like `localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness` to show `"DOWN"`, however `liveness` should still remain `"UP"`.

Is it possible to configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The closest to the desired solution that I could find was:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      group:
        readiness:
          include: readinessState, binders
```

could not, however, limit the binders to kafka only.